# Show that a vector space is spanned by a given set

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to show that $\mathbf{W} = \mathrm{span} \{ 1+x, 1-x^2 \}$ where $\mathbf{W} = \{a + b + ax - bx^2 \mid a,b \in\mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: what's your definition of "spanned vector space" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $a + b + ax - bx^2 = u(1+x)+v(1-x^2)$. Solve for $u$ and $v$, given $a$ and $b$. This proves one inclusion. Do the reverse to prove the other inclusion.

Comment: Doing so proves only half the equality, no?

Comment: @Larry, yes. I've edited my answer. Thanks for the nudge.